# DAX relationship

Tags: filter, powerbi, dax, relationship

I am a beginner in Power BI. Just started working on DAX. I have a question regarding relationship.
I have made four tables i.e. Sales, Products, Product Category, Product Sub Category. Found that relatable columns are automatically picked up. ProductKey column in Product table contains unique Product Key and that propagates Sales Table where Product Key gets repeated. The arrow direction is from Products table to Sales table. '1' is added to Products and a '*' is added to Sales. I think this type of relationship is called 'One to Many' but when I check the properties of the relationship it indicates as 'Many to one'. If tried to change to 'One to Many' it shows error statement. Please help me out of this problem. Thanks.[image]

Comment: check your database, if the system automatically assigned as many-on-1 , there must be "several" products (more than 1) belong to subcategory...

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But if I take Products and Sales tables, there is one time entry of  Product Keys on Products table and they are repeated on Sales table. '*' is with Sales table and '1' is with Products but it is defined as 'Many to one'.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are saying that Product table has '1', while the Sales table has '*', so this is a One-to-Many relationship. However, when you open the relationship properties then you see the 'cardinality' as 'Many to one'. That is only because in the 'Edit relationship' window your table selection sequence is opposite. That is, the Sales table is selected at the top and the Product table is showing in the bottom.
So, summary, the relationship is correct, nothing to be worried about. :)
Rehan

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I reversed their position. Deleted autodetected relationship. Choose Product on top and Sales in the bottom. Cardinality indicated as 'One to Many' but still again it got reverted to 'Many to One'.

Comment: Could you share screenshots. Also, when the cardinality reverses, do the tables also reverse? I have observed that by default, Power BI does show 'Many to One' relationship and display the related tables accordingly (Many on top and One in the bottom).

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to worry about your design however I will suggest you merge "Product Category" with "Product SubCategory" tables so you can achieve a star schema which works best with PowerBI.